# Values not loading in the listview after parsing JSON from the Assets folder

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to get values from a json file in the assets folder and loading it into my simple list view. There's not error in the code and I did try to log all the states. I can see the required values in the log cat but when I using an adapter, the screen loads but I cannot see the data.

I am also using fragments in this test application and I have 4 tabs in total. In one tab I wanted to show all the data loaded from the json file.

Is there something wrong with my adapter?
Some help will be really apreciated.

```
public class Test extends Fragment {

    Context context;

    // TextView tview;
    ImageView iv;
    ImageView iv1;
    private static final String STATE = "state";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = getActivity();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);

        ListView lv1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rowidtext);

        lv1.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), jsonlist, R.layout.xyz,
            new String[] { STATE }, new int[] { R.id.rowidtext }));

        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

            if (json != null) {

                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Information");
                Log.i("Data1234", array.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i <= array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String vstate = c.getString(STATE);

                    Log.i("STATE", vstate);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                    map.put(STATE, vstate);

                    jsonlist.add(map);

                }
                Log.i("Data Coming? ", jsonlist.toString());

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Data Coming? ", jsonlist.toString());
        return rootView;
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

        String json = null;

        try {

            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("testjson1.json");

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
10-28 22:43:08.364: D/dalvikvm(5806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 8% free 2779K/3016K, paused 23ms, total 25ms
10-28 22:43:08.364: I/dalvikvm-heap(5806): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.957MB for 1127536-byte allocation
10-28 22:43:08.474: D/dalvikvm(5806): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3878K/4120K, paused 100ms, total 100ms
10-28 22:43:08.804: D/gralloc_goldfish(5806): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-28 22:43:13.845: I/Data1234(5806): [{"state":"JAVA","outdoorfun":"yes","additionalinfo":"{ search: 'online', website: 'http:\/\/states.arkansas.com', latitudeandlongitude: '93905, 63550}","cold":"no","type":"landlocked"},{"state":"ANDROID","outdoorfun":"no","additionalinfo":"{ search: 'online', website: 'http:\/\/states.chicago.com', latitudeandlongitude: '23905, 45355}","cold":"yes","type":"windy"},{"state":"CORE JAVA","outdoorfun":"no","additionalinfo":"{ search: 'online', website: 'http:\/\/states.chicago.com', latitudeandlongitude: '23905, 45355}","cold":"yes","type":"windy"},null]
10-28 22:43:13.845: I/STATE(5806): JAVA
10-28 22:43:13.845: I/STATE(5806): ANDROID
10-28 22:43:13.845: I/STATE(5806): CORE JAVA
10-28 22:43:13.855: W/System.err(5806): ***org.json.JSONException: Value at 3 is null.***
10-28 22:43:13.855: W/System.err(5806):     at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:259)
10-28 22:43:13.855: W/System.err(5806):     at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:480)
10-28 22:43:13.855: W/System.err(5806):     at com.mike.myapp.Train.onCreateView(Train.java:91)
10-28 22:43:13.855: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-28 22:43:13.865: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at com.mike.myapp.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:91)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:572)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1098)
10-28 22:43:13.875: W/System.err(5806):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:547)
10-28 22:43:13.887: W/System.err(5806):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-28 22:43:13.887: W/System.err(5806):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-28 22:43:13.887: W/System.err(5806):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-28 22:43:13.895: W/System.err(5806):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 22:43:13.895: W/System.err(5806):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 22:43:13.895: W/System.err(5806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-28 22:43:13.895: W/System.err(5806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 22:43:13.905: W/System.err(5806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-28 22:43:13.905: W/System.err(5806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-28 22:43:13.905: W/System.err(5806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-28 22:43:13.905: W/System.err(5806):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this line

```
lv1.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), jsonlist, R.layout.xyz,
            new String[] { STATE }, new int[] { R.id.rowidtext }));
```

After the Json Parsing stuff.

and

```
for (int i = 0; i <= array.length(); i++)
```

**To**

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
```

Here is your Json

```
[
    {
        "state": "JAVA",
        "outdoorfun": "yes",
        "additionalinfo": "{ search: 'online', website: 'http://states.arkansas.com', latitudeandlongitude: '93905, 63550}",
        "cold": "no",
        "type": "landlocked"
    },
    {
        "state": "ANDROID",
        "outdoorfun": "no",
        "additionalinfo": "{ search: 'online', website: 'http://states.chicago.com', latitudeandlongitude: '23905, 45355}",
        "cold": "yes",
        "type": "windy"
    },
    {
        "state": "CORE JAVA",
        "outdoorfun": "no",
        "additionalinfo": "{ search: 'online', website: 'http://states.chicago.com', latitudeandlongitude: '23905, 45355}",
        "cold": "yes",
        "type": "windy"
    }
]
```

as you can see that there is only three element in **JsonArray i.e(0,1,2)** but you are trying to access `index 3` so `org.json.JSONException: Value at 3 is null` is coming.
    I can see the required values in the log cat but when I using an adapter, the screen loads but I cannot see the data.

B'oz `jsonlist` is empty when you are trying to set the Adapter.

Comment: Hey..thanks for the reply..Actually I don't know where exactly to put the adapter in the code. Can you help me out.

Comment: @mike20132013 place adapter before this line. Log.i("Data Coming? ", jsonlist.toString());

Comment: Hey Amit.. I did try it.. It's still not working..:( ..still no values in the list view..:(
Trust me.. I will vote up ..:)

Comment: So stupid of me..I was setting the adapter correctly but the layout R.layout.xyz was supposed to be row..:P

Comment: Thanks anyways @Amit Gupta.. The code was perfectly fine.. it was just that layout..:)